# Does /proc have a device file?

Tags: linux, proc

I can mount a partion of a storage device on any directory I want (for example: `/home/paul/my_partition`) using the partition's device file (for example: `/dev/sdb1`).

But I am wondering, is the `/proc` directory also mounted using a device file?

When I run the mount` command, I get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not have a device in `/dev` associated with it because it does not provide access to a device.

> The `proc` filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem which provides an interface to kernel data structures.  It is commonly mounted at `/proc`.  Most of it is read-only,
>          but some files allow kernel variables to be changed.

(from the Ubuntu `proc(5)` manual).

Answer (score 1):

Actually no. /proc is special purpose filesystem, which provides you access to read/modify some kernel parameters. It acts as an interface to internal data structures in the kernel. It can be used to obtain information about the system and to change certain kernel parameters at runtime with sysctl.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs